# Running websocket-rails on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, rack, eventmachine, puma

I have Rails 4.1.5 app running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, Puma

I managed to get [websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails) working locally with puma.

However, in AWS, I get get the following error in **/var/log/puma/puma.log**

```
Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: async response must have empty headers and body>
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.8.1/lib/puma/server.rb:498:in `handle_request'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.8.1/lib/puma/server.rb:361:in `process_client'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.8.1/lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.8.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.8.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

when the following code runs

`dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('my-app.elasticbeanstalk.com/websocket');`

The error wont be there if i remove

`Thread.new { EventMachine.run } unless EventMachine.reactor_running? && EventMachine.reactor_thread.alive?`

in **config/initializers/event_machine.rb**.

But i need it, else this error will appear in **/var/app/containerfiles/logs/production.log**:

```
RuntimeError (eventmachine not initialized: evma_install_oneshot_timer):
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:323:in `add_oneshot_timer'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:323:in `add_timer'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/timers.rb:50:in `schedule'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/timers.rb:37:in `initialize'
...
```

How do solve `Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: async response must have empty headers and body>`?

Thank you =)

Comment: You'll need to supply some more information on your production configuration. There could be several issues, multiple puma instances without having set `config.synchronize = true` or for instance your nginx configuration. Maybe you find a solution for your Problem in a related issue on github: [Websocket-rails doesn't work on production evironment with Nginx ang Unicorn](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/211).

Comment: @mogg, the solutions don't work =/

Comment: Thrn you'll probably need to tell us a bit more about the related configuration files. Where did you place the code that causes the error and how about an nginx.conf, there should be a `location /websocket`.

Comment: @mogg, I managed to solve it by simply using your threadsocket-rails branch of websocket-rails. Thank you!

However, im getting
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

my **/etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp.conf** is [here](http://pastebin.com/FgZ9xwnr)

`config.synchronize = true` is also set @ **config/initializers/websocket_rails.rb**